# RapidMiner xpath text extraction

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

In RapidMiner, I'm trying to pull data from div class "description". When I test the syntax using Google XPath import XML, it returns the appropriate data. When I try the following in RapidMiner, I get blank results:

```
//h:div[@id='description']/text()
```

This works:

```
//h:div[@id='description']
```

but I get all of the HTML markup data with it.

What do I need to add or remove?

On the same document, I was able to get this to return expected results:

```
//h:label[@id='desc']/text()
```

XML:

```
div id="description" class="longdesc" style=" padding-top: 0px; display: block;" xmlns:IDB="urn:ItemDataBinding">Description Text Here./div
```

Comment: Pretty impossible to answer unless you post your XML. Your XPath, per-se, looks fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't feel the actual XML content was relevant as it works with google xpath but not RapidMiner. Figured I was just missing a simple escape character or something. I have posted the XML I am trying to parse. Thanks!

Comment: I have created a process which works for me. Which operator are you using? Please post a minimal example of your process.